# Building a string with a function call and using it

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to do this?

```
Dog dog = new dog();

String command = ".bark().wag().jump()"; //assume these all exist in the Dog object
```

`dog+command; //I want this to be replaced with dog.bark().wag().jump();` at runtime. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are ways to do this with reflection, but I wouldn't generally advise it. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I and building a query for LDAP, and unlike SQL I have to use a function call instead of being able to write a simple statement. So, I need to be able to add more .and() commands to something like this: List<Person> persons = ldapTemplate.search(
      query().where("objectclass").is("person"),
             .and(query().where("cn").is("Doe").or("cn").is("Doo));

Comment: You should have put that comment’s content into the question.

Comment: I was trying to keep my question simple.

Comment: Sounds like `CriteriaBuilder` from JPA would do the job. Never ask a simple question when you can ask a clear question ;-)

Comment: `dog+command;` will yield string concatenation  `dog.toString().concat(".bark().wag().jump()")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create and use custom annotatons with reflection to tag the methods with a name:

```
@Command(name="bark")
public void bark() {
    System.out.println("Le BARK, le WOOF! Je suis un chien!");
}
```

You could just query the method name, but I prefer making annotations so I can change the method name to whatever I want whenever I want and maintain the same command name.

Although it would probably be better to create a method in the class like:

```
public void executeCommand(String command) {
    if (command.contains("bark") {
       bark();
    }
}
```

If you're looking for a way to save your fingers from becoming stumps from typing verbose java code, I'm afraid there's no *real* shortcut for that that I'm aware of. Typically I've found when I have tried similar things I end up typing a lot more than if I had just done it straight-up.

Comment: split command on `().` and then perform switch case in a `for loop`...

Comment: Yeah. I didn't bother with their specific case because my answer is pretty broad to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CriteriaBuilder is what I need. Thanks to [sorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15177026/sorin)